# How to get file from directory with pattern/filter

Tags: java, regex, file, filter, directory

I have to get a file from a PDF files directory. I have problem that I haven't a field to concant all data to find the file.

**Here's an example:**

File name:

```
Comp_20120619_170310_2_632128_FC_A_8_23903.pdf
```

File name generate:

```
Comp_20120619_--------_2_632128_FC_A_8_23903.pdf
```

I dont' have the field `"--------"` to make file COMPLETE name.

I'm trying with `File.list` but I cannot find the correct file.

Comment: I don't know much java, but what about "Comp_20120619_*_2_632128_FC_A_8_23903.pdf"?

Comment: I thought these, but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define a [FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) to match against the filenames, and return true if the filename matches what you're looking for.

```
    File dir = new File("/path/to/pdfs");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.matches("Comp_20120619_[^_]*_2_632128_FC_A_8_23903.pdf");
        }
    });
```

The `listFiles()` method returns an array of File objects. This makes sense, because there might be more than one file that matches the pattern (in theory at least, albeit not necessarily in your system).

I've used a regular expression to match the filename, using `[^_]*` to match the section you're not sure about. However, you can use any function that will return a boolean if the filename matches. For example, you could use `startsWith` and `endsWith` instead of a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm trying to use this Regexp, I wil tell you the result. I build dinamically the others parts of file name, for example : "Comp_"+date+"_*_"+fbo.suc()+"_"+fbo.trans()+"_"+fbo.type()+"_"+fbo.letter()+"_"+fbo.pointvta()+"_"+fbo.ticketnumber()+".pdf";

Comment: Remember that it's a regex and not a file glob. So if you want to match any text, it's ".*" and not "*". Don't forget to add the underscores to your regex too!

Comment: Also you need to escape the dots, as a dot in RegEx means "any character". So it should be "Comp_20120619_[^_]*_2_632128_FC_A_8_23903\\.pdf". (Two backslashes are needed, as you also need to adhere to the java escaping rules: two backslahes in the literal mean one in the string)

Comment: How to pass the regex from the outside of accept method?

Answer (score 1):

What's your problem with `list()` ?

```
File folder = new File("path/to/pdffilefolder");
String[] allFilesInThatFolder = folder.list();
// contains only files, no folders.
```

Comment: I have a problem with the filter setted, so these method return different files.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible tu use a WildcardFileFilter (org.apache.commons.io.filefilter)

The code looks simple :

```
FilenameFilter filenameFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("Comp_20120619_*_2_632128_FC_A_8_23903.pdf");
String[] pdfFileNames = yourDir.list(filenameFilter);
if(pdfFileNames != null ) {
    for (String pdfName : pdfFileNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works.. (please read comments for explanation)

```
String[] pdfFiles= yourDir.listFiles(getFileNameFilterMachingWithFileName("Comp_20120619_"));



private FilenameFilter getFileNameFilterMachingWithFileName(final String 
fileNameStart) {
        return new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
             public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
               return (name.toUpperCase().startsWith(fileNameStart.toUpperCase()) && name.toUpperCase().endsWith(".PDF"));          
             }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: listFiles with file name filter will give you only files which matches your filtering criteria. Here I'm picking up only files whose name start with mentioned criteria (passed as a parameter to method getFileNameFilterMachingWithFileName("Comp_20120619_")) and ends with ".pdf" extension, just to pick up only pdfs. also this is compared in case insensitive manner to pick all files even on linux like OS with case sensitive file system.

Comment: can you put your comment in the answer itself?