# How to count number of file with specific name pattern in some particular directory in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, file

I am trying to count suppose file having name starting with today date as **update_04082014_something-something.txt** in some particular directory.i got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515150/how-to-get-file-from-directory-with-pattern-filter) for finding pattern but m not sure how to count total files having this pattern

Comment: total = dir.listFiles(...).length

Comment: So, you want to find all files with a particular pattern like `something_04082014_something` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// get each file name in that particular directory here
    String s = "update_04082014_something-something.txt"; // matches
    String s1 = "update_05082014_something-something.txt"; // doesnt match
    String ddmmyy = "04082014";
    String pattern = ".*?_" + ddmmyy + ".*";
    System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
    System.out.println(s1.matches(pattern));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time accept method returns true add 1 to the counter (e.g i). i is the total of files matching the pattern.