# Faster way to collect in arraylist in java

Tags: java, list, java-8, stream

I have a directory with many files and want to filter the one with a certain name and save them in the `fileList` ArrayList and it works in this way but it takes much time. Is there a way to make this faster?

```
String processingDir = "C:/Users/Ferid/Desktop/20181024";
String CorrId = "00a3d321-171c-484a-ad7c-74e22ffa3625");
Path dirPath = Paths.get(processingDir);       

ArrayList<Path> fileList;

try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(dirPath))
{           
    fileList = paths.filter(t -> (t.getFileName().toString().indexOf("EPX_" + 
    corrId + "_") >= 0)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

The walking through the directory in the try condition is not taking much time but the collecting it in `fileList` is taking much time and I do not know which operation it is exactly which has this poor performance or which of them to improve. (This is not the complete code of course, just the relevant things)

Comment: why do you think that collecting is the expensive part? Note that everything you ask the stream to do (e.g. `filter`, `map`, etc.) is usually only carried out when calling a terminating method, which `collect` is.

Comment: I have tested it, and that line `fileList = paths.filter(t -> (t.getFileName().toString().indexOf("EPX_" + 
corrId + "_") >= 0)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
` was the one which took very much time

Comment: See if it can be converted to parallel stream.

Comment: FileNameFilter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515150/how-to-get-file-from-directory-with-pattern-filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `java.nio.file.Files.walk(Path)` api:

> Return a Stream that is **lazily populated** with Path by walking the file
>   tree rooted at a given starting file.

That's why it gives you the impression that "walking through the directory in the try condition is not taking much time".

Actually, the real deal is mostly done on `collect` and it is not collect's mechanism fault for being slow.

Answer (score 2):

If scanning the files each time is too slow you can build an index of files, either on startup or persisted and maintained as files change.

You could use a [Watch Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to be notified when files are added or removed while the program is running.

This would be much faster to query as it would be entirely in memory. It would take the same amount of time to load the first time but could be loading the background before you need it initially.

e.g.

```
static Map<String, List<Path>> pathMap;
public static void initPathMap(String processingDir) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(processingDir))) {
        pathMap = paths.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                p -> getCorrId(p.getFileName().toString())));
    }
    pathMap.remove(""); // remove entries without a corrId.
}


private static String getCorrId(String fileName) {
    int start = fileName.indexOf("EPX_");
    if (start < 0)
        return "";
    int end = fileName.indexOf("_", start + 4);
    if (end < 0)
        return "";
    return fileName.substring(start + 4, end);
}

// later 
    String corrId = "00a3d321-171c-484a-ad7c-74e22ffa3625";
    List<Path> pathList = pathMap.get(corrId); // very fast.
```

---

You can make this code cleaner by writing the following, however, I wouldn't expect it to be much faster.

```
List<Path> fileList;

try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(dirPath)) {           
    String find = "EPX_" + corrId + "_"; // only calculate this once
    fileList = paths.filter(t -> t.getFileName().contains(find))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

The cost is in the time taken to scan the files of the directory.  The cost of processing the file names is far, far less.

Using an SSD, or only scanning directories already cached in memory would speed this up dramatically.

One way to test this is to perform the operation more than once after a clean boot (so it's not cached).  The amount the first run takes longer tells you how much time was spent loading the data from disk.

Comment: Sadly this access to the directory is only for testing it, I have to improve the performance in the code because it is not for a local improvement on my device

Comment: @SilverFullbuster if 1% of the time is spent in your code, you can't improve it by more than 1%

Comment: @SilverFullbuster what you can do is avoid walking the directory by loading that information in advance and caching it.

Comment: thank you for your efforts! Some thoughts helped me but your last edited suggestion throws some ava.lang.NullPointerException and I could not figure out why